# Simple Spark App on single machine testing cluster got killed due to OutOfMemoryError

Tags: scala, out-of-memory, apache-spark

I am trying to run the simply app in spark [tutorial](http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.1/quick-start.html) on my single machine cluster. I have Hadoop 2.2 running on my machine. I am using mac with 8GB RAM.

```
steven@eva-2 /o/s/a/t/scala-2.10> jps
6160 Jps
5841 Worker
4005 SecondaryNameNode
1460 NailgunRunner
3828 NameNode
3907 DataNode
1382 
4106 ResourceManager
5751 Master
4185 NodeManager
```

Also, I am able to access the Web UI (able to see the program is finished but killed). The problem is when I run this programm:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

object SimplyApp extends App {
  val logFile = "/opt/spark-0.9.0-incubating-bin-hadoop2/README.md"

  val conf = new SparkConf()
    .setMaster("spark://eva-2.local:7077")
    .setAppName("Simple App")
    .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")

  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val logData = sc.textFile(logFile, 2).cache()
  val numAs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("a")).count()
  val numBs = logData.filter(line => line.contains("b")).count()
  println("Lines with a: %s, Lines with b: %s".format(numAs, numBs))
  println(numAs)
}
```

The error is:

```
14/06/03 20:46:19 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterActor$BlockManagerInfo: Registering block manager 10.10.121.52:53320 with 589.2 MB RAM
14/06/03 20:46:20 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost TID 1 (task 0.0:1)
14/06/03 20:46:20 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Loss was due to java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

I tried to give it more memory, but still the same problem. Does anyone know how to handle this? Thank you.

Comment: have you tried with `setMaster("local[4]")` ?  That's local mode.  It looks like your slave is misconfigured. The sample file is quite small to generate this error. Also not to overlook the obvious: do you have enough free mem on your machine?

Comment: how are you starting the local cluster?

Comment: @maasg Hey. I just start the cluster (weird, change IP and the launch script works). Now, I am trying to use your solution. I changed the memory to a small number, but still face the problem. Than I set master as `local[4]`, it works. But what I want to do is to use the spark URL to set the master, since I can test locally and deploy to the cluster conveniently. Am I right?

Comment: How many workers are you deploying alongside the master? How much memory do they have?

Comment: @maasg I only use one worker on my machine. And it has the default memory(since I don't change `spark-env.sh`) which is system memory minus 1GB

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark, as I'd need to know the cluster config to pin-point the issue, but most probably is in these lines:

`spark.executor.memory` is the amount of memory that the executor requires. It's an application setting. On the other hand, if you are running in an standalone cluster (as you're using a master url) the memory available to the workers is defined by the env var: `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY`. It follows:  `spark.executor.memory < SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY`.

Given you're processing a file of few Kb, try lowering `spark.executor.memory` to ~100Mb or so.  The hint is to lower the `spark.executor.memory` setting, not to increase it.